# Reduce the size of main.js Angular 11

Tags: optimization, angular-cli

I encouter a problem with my app that has a main.js with a size of 8.34 MB by defalt (ng build).
I tested a lot ! of things to reduce it but i just don't arrive to..

I really need that the size be less than 2 mb.. ( and i think it's huge too..)
Thanks for help !
[image]
What i tried (size of main.js) :

```
ng build = 8.34MB
ng build --prod = 7.71 MB
ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer = 7.71 MB
ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer && gzipper compress ./dist = ...
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "app",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --hmr",
        "build": "ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer && gzipper compress ./dist",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "11.1.2",
        "@angular/cdk": "^11.1.2",
        "@angular/common": "11.1.2",
        "@angular/compiler": "11.1.2",
        "@angular/core": "11.1.2",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33",
        "@angular/forms": "11.1.2",
        "@angular/material": "^11.1.2",
        "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^11.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "11.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.1.2",
        "@angular/router": "11.1.2",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
        "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^17.0.0",
        "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^19.0.0",
        "@types/d3-shape": "^2.0.0",
        "ajv": "^7.0.4",
        "angular-calendar": "^0.28.22",
        "angular-feather": "^6.1.0",
        "angular-ng-autocomplete": "^2.0.5",
        "apexcharts": "^3.24.0",
        "c3": "^0.7.20",
        "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
        "chartist": "^0.11.4",
        "core-js": "^3.8.3",
        "d3": "^6.5.0",
        "date-fns": "^2.17.0",
        "extend": "^3.0.2",
        "gulp-cli": "^2.3.0",
        "gzipper": "^4.4.0",
        "handlebars": "^4.7.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.20",
        "mat-table-exporter": "^9.1.0",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "ng-apexcharts": "^1.5.7",
        "ng-chartist": "4.1.0",
        "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.14",
        "ng2-charts": "^2.4.2",
        "ng2-completer": "^9.0.1",
        "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
        "ng2-file-upload": "^1.4.0",
        "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
        "ngx-clipboard": "^14.0.1",
        "ngx-cookie-service": "^11.0.2",
        "ngx-custom-validators": "11.0.1",
        "ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0",
        "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.1.0",
        "ngx-quill": "^13.1.0",
        "quill": "^1.3.7",
        "rxjs": "~6.6.3",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.3",
        "sass": "^1.32.6",
        "sweetalert2": "^10.14.0",
        "tslib": "^2.1.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.1101.4",
        "@angular/cli": "11.1.4",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "11.1.2",
        "@types/chartist": "0.11.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.3",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
        "@types/node": "^14.14.25",
        "codelyzer": "^6.0.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~6.0.0",
        "karma": "~6.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
        "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
        "protractor": "~7.0.0",
        "ts-node": "~9.1.1",
        "tslint": "~6.1.0",
        "typescript": "^4.1.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what much we can do about this, looks like you have a lot of 3rd party dependencies, are those libs tree shakable? For example `sweetalert2` is not. I suggest you try `webpack-bundle-analyzer` and see what's causing bloat in your app.

Comment: It seems that the gzipped is working but my page is just loading the main.js and not the main.js.gz...
In my dist directory i have the content .js and .js.gz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reduced the size from 8.34 MB to 1.7 MB by doing what i already did.
This :

`ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer && gzipper compress ./dist`

And by configuring my web server to use this : (apache)

```
# GZIP compression for text files: HTML, CSS, JS, Text, XML, fonts
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json // for my translation file
</IfModule>
```

Comment: that is very large still all you have done is gzipped it, which any server would do anyway when serving it, are you using modules and lazy loading or just one big module

Comment: 1.7MB is quite good, not in my case, the content is now really faster to load. Yes modules and lazy loading. This app has been deleted few months ago and has been replaced, but the case has been the same, and we gzip again for better results

Comment: ok i have built quite large apps and usually come in around 1.5mb with 197kb gzip just seemed quite large 8mb